# Accessing from another System with the same user

Tags: permissions

I have 2 Linux on the same pc, one is Ubuntu and the other is CrunchBang.
I set the same value as user and password for both.

Now I am on cranchbang partition and can access to to ubuntu partition home..

Why I can delete file on my home in Ubuntu.....

One can delete someone else files only because they have the same value of user ?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Basically, permissions are based on user (or group) **ID**, not their name or password. So I suspect your users A and B in both systems to have identical IDs (e.g. 1001), which makes possible any kind of modification in A's directories for B and vice versa.

You can check this by

```
id -u
```

for users on both systems. If necessary, user ID can be changed using

```
usermod -u <newID> <username>
```

Comment: Ok I ll see Thank you very much But it is not a correct think: teorically Hackers can take advantage of it. I am surprised that developer didnt notice it. MAYBE the id value setting depend on the hardware.
But one can insert a LiveCD and try..... I think it should depende on the time of creation Thank you, later I will check

Comment: @user282750 If a person is able to get physical access to a machine and uses a LiveCD, he is able to access anything on any physical storage of the machine. In this case no special user or associated rights are necessary, because at this point an attacker gains root's rights. Access to stored data is then only avoidable if (strong) encryption has been used.